# groupon json request not working

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp, groupon

I can't seem to get jquery to return anything from the groupon API.

When I check in [apigee](https://apigee.com/console/groupon_api2#) I can do a simple get request to get all divisions.

But when I try in JSFiddle it ain't working

```
$.get('https://api.groupon.com/v2/divisions.json?client_id=b91d375e38147f3c1e0339a3588d0b791c190424', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

The $.get above returns a response that's empty.

```
$.getJSON("https://api.groupon.com/v2/divisions.json?client_id=b91d375e38147f3c1e0339a3588d0b791c190424&jsoncallback=?", function(json) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

This one returns an error

```
invalid label
[Break On This Error] {"divisions":[{"id":"abbotsford","name...owCustomerEnabled":false,"areas":[]}]}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the JSFIDDLE :

> [http://jsfiddle.net/fMzeK/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/fMzeK/2/)

Comment: what does it say in the error?

Comment: I added the errormessage and  jsfiddle page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need JSONP because it will be cross domain:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.groupon.com/v2/divisions.json?client_id=b91d375e38147f3c1e0339a3588d0b791c190424', 
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
        alert(data.divisions);
}});
```

Comment: it seems to return the data alright but it still gives this warning :Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/json.

Comment: Javascript can be transferred with pretty much any encoding.  You shouldn't worry to much about it :)